# Identifying a USB WiFi adapter

Tags: usb, wifi-driver

I have a USB WiFi adapter that came with a Dell SX260.  The PC has died but I'm trying to use the WiFi adapter.  It slides onto the top and is dark grey and oval(think the saucer section of the Enterprise for the shape).  Windows isn't automatically identifying it but I'm hoping if I can figure out what model it is I can download the right drivers.  It has the Dell logo on it, but I can't seem to find a model number

Comment: Does it show up as an 'unknown device' in the device manager? If it does then please right click, go to details and select the property 'Hardware IDs'. Add those to the post.

Comment: BTW, check out [Are “Guessing Game” type questions allowed on SU?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6073/are-guessing-game-type-questions-allowed-on-su). Based on that, I've voted to close as Too Localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info provided, I'm assuming it's this:

[image]

Which is the Dell TrueMobile 1180 Wireless USB Adapter.

Check out Dell's [driver page for the SX260](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/Product/optiplex-sx260) for drivers for it.

Comment: That would appear to be it